# Can I add comments with Asana API?

Tags: asana

Can I add comments to task using Asana API?

I want to write hook to git in which after every local commit I would add comment to Asana and after every push I'd add comment with links to commits in github (or any other "git commit viewer").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I work at Asana).

Yes. See the section in the developer documentation for stories, under "Commenting on an object":

https://asana.com/developers/api-reference/stories

Comment: Thanks, I've missed that :-)